# strtol not changing errno

Tags: c, errno, strtol

I'm working on a program that performs calculations given a char array that represents a time in the format `HH:MM:SS`. It has to parse the individual time units.
Here's a cut down version of my code, just focusing on the hours:

```
unsigned long parseTime(const char *time)
{
    int base = 10;                    //base 10
    long hours = 60;                  //defaults to something out of range
    char localTime[BUFSIZ]            //declares a local array
    strncpy(localTime, time, BUFSIZ); //copies parameter array to local
    errno = 0;                        //sets errno to 0

    char *par;                        //pointer
    par = strchr(localTime, ':');     //parses to the nearest ':'
    localTime[par - localTime] = '\0';  //sets the ':' to null character

    hours = strtol(localTime, &par, base); //updates hours to parsed numbers in the char array
    printf("errno is: %d\n", errno);       //checks errno
    errno = 0;                             //resets errno to 0
    par++;                                 //moves pointer past the null character
}
```

The problem is that if the input is invalid (e.g. `aa:13:13`), `strtol()` apparently doesn't detect an error because it's not updating `errno` to `1`, so I can't do error handling. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: `printf("errno is: %d\n");` should probably be `printf("errno is: %d\n", errno);` doesn't it?

Comment: Oh yes, that's in my real code. I just forgot to type it  here. Edited.

Comment: For such specific parsing, don't use the standard functions, but parse by character.

Comment: — 1 for fake code. I wasted time writing an answer for the non-cause of your problem.

Comment: @Olaf: There's no reason not to use the standard functions.

Comment: Rolled back. You must not change significant parts of the question rendering an answer invalid!

Comment: Well that doesn't change the real problem.

Comment: @Olaf: That rollback was inappropriate. My answer is useless and I'm deleting it. Yes the fake code was bad but re-breaking the question so that it can't get useful answers is not helping anyone.

Comment: @R..: You don't have good control of what you read. Try `12345:3:3`.

Comment: @R.. just following rules. I was not aware at that momentr OP was in mistake, but suspected he is life-editing his question.

Comment: You do not need to set the `:` to `\0` (at least not for `strtol()`), it just stops at the first invalid char for the specified base.

Comment: @Olaf: `if (endptr-startptr != 2)`... :-)

Comment: strtol() only sets errno if the value it parsed overflowed, you get ERANGE.  Failure to parse the entire string is detected through its 3rd argument, it will point to the first non-convertible character.  The '.' in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have explained, `strtol` may not update `errno` in case it cannot perform any conversion.  The C Standard only documents that `errnor` be set to `ERANGE` in case the converted value does not fit in a `long` integer.

Your code has other issues:

- Copying the string with `strncpy` is incorrect: in case the source string is longer than `BUFSIZ`, `localTime` will not be null terminated.  Avoid `strncpy`, a poorly understood function that almost never fits the purpose.
- In this case, you no not need to clear the `:` to `'\0'`, `strtol` will stop at the first non digit character. `localTime[par - localTime] = '\0';` is a complicated way to write `*par = '\0';`

A much simpler version is this:

```
long parseTime(const char *time) {
    char *par;
    long hours;

    if (!isdigit((unsigned char)*time) {
        /* invalid format */
        return -1;
    }
    errno = 0;
    hours = strtol(time, &par, 10);
    if (errno != 0) {
        /* overflow */
        return -2;
    }
    /* you may want to check that hour is within a decent range... */
    if (*par != ':') {
        /* invalid format */
        return -3;
    }
    par++;
    /* now you can parse further fields... */
    return hours;
}
```

I changed the return type to `long` so you can easily check for invalid format and even determine which error from a negative return value.

For an even simpler alternative, use `sscanf`:

```
long parseTime(const char *time) {
    unsigned int hours, minutes, seconds;
    char c;

    if (sscanf(time, "%u:%u:%u%c", &hours, &minutes, &seconds, &c) != 3) {
        /* invalid format */
        return -1;
    }
    if (hours > 1000 || minutes > 59 || seconds > 59) {
        /* invalid values */
        return -2;
    }
    return hours * 3600L + minutes * 60 + seconds;
}
```

This approach still accepts incorrect strings such as `1: 1: 1` or `12:00000002:1`.  Parsing the string by hand seem the most concise and efficient solution.

Comment: That makes sense. I tried to use isdigit() earlier but it was incorrect because I was doing isdigit(strtol()).

Comment: 1) After `strtol(localTime, &par, 10)`, checking `localTIme != par` is usefult to know _some_ conversion happened. 2) `"%2u:%2u:%2u%c"` is a little closer to `HH:MM:SS`.  Still a good start

Comment: @chux: since `*time` is a digit, we will necessarily have a conversion and `par != time`.  Format `HH:MM:SS` could be validated with a call to `sscanf("%2[0-9]:%1[0-9]%1[0-9]:%1[0-9]%1[0-9]%c",  ...) == 5` but manual validation would be just as simple.  The specification does not say how many digits are allowed for the hour field, `{1,2}` seems correct to me, but `{1,}` might be OK too.

Answer (score 3):

`strtol` is not required to produce an error code when no conversion can be performed. Instead you should use the second argument which stores the final position after conversion and compare it to the initial position.

BTW there are numerous other errors in your code that do not affect the problem you're seeing but which should also be fixed, such as incorrect use of `strncpy`.

Answer (score 0):

A useful trick with `sscanf()` is that code can do multiple passes to detect errant input:

```
// HH:MM:SS
int parseTime(const char *hms, unsigned long *secs) {
  int n = 0;
  // Check for valid text
  sscanf(hms "%*[0-2]%*[0-9]:%*[0-5]%*[0-9]:%*[0-5]%*[0-9]%n", &n);
  if (n == 0) return -1; // fail

  // Scan and convert to integers
  unsigned h,m,s;
  sscanf(hms "%u:%u:%u", &h, &m, &s);
  // Range checks as needed
  if (h >= 24 || m >= 60 || s >= 60) return -1;

  *sec = (h*60 + m)*60L + s;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After `hours = strtol(localTime, &par, base);` statement you have to first save the value of errno. Because after this statement you are going to call `printf()` statement that also set `errno` accordingly.

```
printf("errno is: %d\n", errno);
```

So in this statement "errno" gives the error indication for `printf()` not for `strtol()`... To do so save "errno" before calling any library function because most of the library function interact with "errno".
The correct use is :

```
hours = strtol(localTime, &par, base);
int saved_error = errno;       // Saving the error...
printf("errno is: %d\n", saved_error);
```

Now check it. It will give correct output surely...And one more thing to convert this `errno` to some meaningful string to represent error use `strerror()` function as :

```
printf("Error is: %s\n", strerror(saved_error));
```

Comment: Saving `errno` to another `int` variable right after `strtol` doesn't help in my case for some reason. `99999999999999` is parsed with that "storage" variable (`saved_error` in your case) staying `0` anyways.

Comment: @Trudy could you please give an example to understand your case in better way?